# Attach a webView instance variable to a Web View object

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, google-maps

Im trying to follow this [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/tutorial-iphone) 
The tutorial is a bit out dated because NIB files dont get used anymore like this with the xCode storyboards. So my question is how do I attach the webView instance variable to the Web View object? This is probably a really basic question hence im new to this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oke i found out how to do it.
Here is a [tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=tIyQP3A7amw#t=201s) how to create a webView, the video starts at the whole delegate thing where i struggled with. 
The video is still for the interface builder instead of the storyboard but the idea is very much the same.